# MySQL UPDATE to calculate value using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I would like to calculate the value of a company's market share using the percentage share in one table and the total market size from another table, and update the former table with the result.

I have been researching quite a bit but not found a good answer for this. So I've only arrived at the following query, which times out with `Lock wait timeout exceeded` after I've increased this parameter to 150 sec. Looks like the query is wrong, or at least quite inefficient. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE MarketShares AS mShares
JOIN MarketSizes AS mSizes
    ON mSizes.year = mShares.year
    AND mSizes.category = mShares.category
    AND mSizes.countryID = mShares.countryID
SET mShares.mShareValue = mShares.mShare * mSizes.retailYoY /100
WHERE mSizes.year = mShares.year
    AND mSizes.emCategory = mShares.emCategory
    AND mSizes.countryID = mShares.countryID;
```

The next table is the target, and has slightly more than 1 mio rows:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CA.MarketShares (
  marketShareID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  category INT NOT NULL,
  companyID INT NOT NULL ,
  countryID INT NOT NULL,
  year INT NULL,
  mShare DEC(20,4) NULL,
  mShareValue DEC(20,4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emMarketShareID))
```

The following table's retailYoY variable provides the market size info, and has some 450K rows:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CA.MarketSizes (
  marketSizeID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  category INT NOT NULL,
  year INT NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL,
  retailYoY DEC(20,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (marketSizeID))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: `EXPLAIN UPDATE..` results in the following:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'mShares', 'ALL', 'brandShare_countries', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1048110', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'mSizes', 'ref', 'marketSize_fk_countries', 'emMarketSize_fk_countries', '4', 'consumeralpha.mShares.countryID', '2485', 'Using where'
```

It would seem that the number of rows for the `mSizes` table should be >400K.

Comment: What are your indexes? Could you add an `EXPLAIN` of the query to the question?

Comment: Thanks, Joachim. There are no indexes other than for the primary keys;  countryIDs are subject to foreign key constraints in both tables.

Comment: If you have a while to create an index, `CREATE INDEX ix_marketshares ON MarketShares(year, category)` should be worth benchmarking.

Comment: Index in the works, for over 10 min by now. Do you see any other ways to write the query (if at all correct..) more efficiently?

Comment: Not really, it's about as straight forward a join as you can get, and MySQL tends to like straight forward. Without indexes it'll have to go through all 1M rows one by one and try to match them with the 450k rows by going through them one by one too, so not much to do in the way of rewriting the query. Indexes should help a lot for the join.

Comment: Question is if an index on only one of the tables speeds it up sufficiently, you'll have to benchmark that since I can't really test with that amount of data.

Comment: Should I then create an index for all three columns (category, year, and country), or is country already taken care off through the foreign key constraint?

Comment: In any case, after adding the new indexes to both tables fairly quickly using `ALTER TABLE`, the query above takes only 30 seconds.

Comment: An index on all 3 is most likely faster for this question, but less reusable for other questions. Keep in mind that an index on (a,b) works for queries on a and a+b, but not on b. As to why no update, how are you seeing that? Random sample?

Comment: Thanks for you help. Impressive how much of a difference the indexes make. The query does in fact update, but only some 80 percent of the rows. I suspect this is more a data issue than a SQL issue, so I got to dig a bit into numbers & categories.